# Why does binding to the Picker not work anymore in swiftui?

Tags: swiftui

When I run a Picker Code in the Simulator or the Canvas, the Picker goes always back to the first option with an animation or just freezes. This happens since last Thursday/Friday. So I checked some old simple code, where it worked before that and it doesn't work for me there, too.
This is the simple old Code. It doesn't work anymore in beta 3, 4 and 5.

```
struct PickerView : View {
    @State var selectedOptionIndex = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Option: \(selectedOptionIndex)")
            Picker(selection: $selectedOptionIndex, label: Text("")) {
                Text("Option 1")
                Text("Option 2")
                Text("Option 3")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my newer code, I used `@ObservedObject`, but also here it doesn't work. 
Also I don't get any errors and it builds and runs. 
Thank you for any pointers.

----**EDIT**----- **Please look at the answer first**

After the help, that I could use the `.tag()` behind all `Text()`like `Text("Option 1").tag()`, it now takes the initial value and updates it inside the view. If I use `@ObservedObject` like here:

```
struct PickerView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data: Model

    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Picker(selection: $data.exercise, label: Text("select exercise")) {
                    ForEach(data.exercises, id: \.self) { exercise in
                        Text("\(exercise)").tag(self.data.exercises.firstIndex(of: exercise))
                    }
                }
.frame(width: width, height: (height/2), alignment: .center)
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't reflect changes on the value, if I make these changes in another view, one navigationlink further. And also it doesn't seem to work with the my code above, where I use `firstIndex(of: exercise)`

---**EDIT**---
 Now the code above works if I change 
`Text("\(exercise)").tag(self.data.exercises.firstIndex(of: exercise))`
into 
`Text("\(exercise)").tag(self.data.exercises.firstIndex(of: exercise)!)` 
because it couldn't work with an optional.

Comment: Is your array count fixed? Or may it grow at any time?

Comment: Array count is fixed. But I use a Picker also to select the amount of time for a timer. Technically it should count down when the timer has started, but it doesn't anymore, which doesn't bother me.

Comment: Ok, I see that you found the `Optional` problem. Well spotted! The reason I asked about the fixed array, is because if you know the array won't change, you may use `ForEach(0..<data.excercises.count) { idx in }`. That way you get the index easily. Again, that only works if the array doesn't change. Release notes say: "You shouldn’t pass a range that changes at runtime. If you use a variable that changes at runtime to define the range, the list displays views according to the initial range and ignores any subsequent updates to the range". Cheers.

Comment: That makes the code more readable! Thanks for the explanation also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to simplify the code a bit without the need of operating on indicies and tags.

At first, make sure to conform your model to `Identifiable` protocol like this (this is actually a key part, as it enables SwiftUI to differentiate elements):

```
public enum EditScheduleMode: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case closeSchedule
    case openSchedule
    
    public var id: EditScheduleMode { self }
    
    var localizedTitle: String { ... }
}
```

Then you can declare viewModel like this:

```
public class EditScheduleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var editScheduleMode = EditScheduleMode.closeSchedule
    public let modes = EditScheduleMode.allCases
}
```

and UI:

```
struct ModeSelectionView: View {
    private let elements: [EditScheduleMode]
    @Binding private var selectedElement: EditScheduleMode
    
    internal init?(elements: [EditScheduleMode],
                   selectedElement: Binding<EditScheduleMode>) {
        self.elements = elements
        _selectedElement = selectedElement
    }
    
    internal var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("", selection: $selectedElement) {
                ForEach(elements) { element in
                    Text(element.localizedTitle)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        }
    }
}
```

With all of those you can create a view like this:

```
ModeSelectionView(elements: viewModel.modes, selectedElement: $viewModel.editScheduleMode)
```

Answer (score 21):

The answer summarized:

1. With the `.tag()` behind the Options it works. It would look like following:

```
Picker(selection: $selectedOptionIndex, label: Text("")) {
                ForEach(1...3) { index in
                    Text("Option \(index)").tag(index)
                }
            }
```

2. If you use a range of Objects it could look like this:

```
Picker(selection: $data.exercises, label: Text("")) {
                ForEach(0..<data.exercises.count) { index in
                    Text("\(data.exercises[index])").tag(index)
                }
            }
```

I am not sure if it is intended, that `.tag()` is needed to be used here, but it's at least a workaround.

Comment: You can also use `data.exercises.indices` to get a range of all indices. Just for the looks.

Comment: The tag doesn't really matter in my code. But the Optional problem does! Thank you for  point it out: "it( Picker ) couldn't work with an optional."